# Facebook add page tab problems

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a popup shown using Facebook JS SDK:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'pagetab',
    redirect_uri: 'http://my_domain/fb_page_tab'
}, function(response) { alert('Popup closed!'); });
```

The thing is, when I'm using 'redirect_uri' param, I just get:

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Which is really weird, because the same URL works fine when I'm using URL method instead of JS.
Back to the popup - if I click 'OK' I get redirected inside the popup to the facebook page. If I close it - the callback function is invoked properly and I can see my alert with 'Popup closed'.

I also get this warning when using 'redirect_uri':

> When using FB.ui, you should not specify a redirect_uri.

So, I've tried to use 'next' param instead of 'redirect_uri' (I've seen this somewhere and thought I could try it).

This resulted in correctly displayed popup - I can choose to which page I want to add my app (YAY!). However, the popup doesn't close itself after adding the app, it redirects me to the 'next' URL inside the popup. It also doesn't invoke the callback, so when I close the popup - there's no 'Popup closed' alert.

So, my question is: what is the proper way of showing this popup with JS? And shouldn't this popup close itself after adding app to the page, and redirect me to the given URL inside the main window?